# Order By then Group?

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables, the first, `hotel_info` that has fields such as(`hotel_id`,`hotel_name`,`location`) and a second table `rooms`, that has room information such as(`room_id`,`room_name`,`hotel_id`,`rate`,`description`). I want a query that returns the minimum room rate for a hotel and all information about the hotel from the `hotel_info` table. So far I have this query that is working properly but its not returning the minimum room rate.

```
SELECT a.hotel_id,a.hotel_name ,a.location, b.rate FROM hotel_info a 
LEFT JOIN rooms b ON b.hotel_id=a.hotel_id 
GROUP BY hotel_id
```

How get the minimum room rate per hotel?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mysql function min() such as

```
select a.hotel_id, min(b.rate) 
from hotel_info a 
left join rooms b on b.hotel_id = a.hotel_id 
group by a.hotel_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.hotel_id, a.hotel_name, a.location, min(b.rate) as min_rate 
FROM hotel_info a 
LEFT JOIN rooms b ON b.hotel_id = a.hotel_id 
GROUP BY a.hotel_id, a.hotel_name, a.location
```